# Quadratic Transformation of the Hypergeometric Function 2F1

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

The function ${}_2F_1\Big(\frac{a-b}{2},\frac{a+b-1}{2};c;y\Big)$ can be transformed  (as reported by A. Erdélyi) by the following formula

${}_2F_1\Big(\frac{a-b}{2},\frac{a+b-1}{2};c;y\Big)=
(1-z)^{1-b}{}_2F_1\Big(a,a-1;b;z\Big)
$

for

$y =4z(1-z)$, and  $\quad a,b,c \in\mathbb{R}$

The problem is that solving the equation $y =4z(1-z)$ for the value of $z$ yields two solutions

$z_1 = \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-y}\right)$

and

$z_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{1-y}\right)$

Therefore, should the resultant transformation include both values of $z_1$ and $z_2$? or just use one value of them and ignore the second one.

How to include both values in one answer?

Comment: Can you cite a source?  These formulas seems incorrect - for one, the lhs depends on c while the rhs does not.  It will be simpler to examine the full region of valididity of the formula once it is correct...

Comment: Handbook of Special Functions by Yury A. Brychkov chapter 8, Eq.(40)

Comment: As it stands, the lhs and rhs satisfy different (2nd order) linear ODEs, so they really can't be the same.  Seems like you have found a typo in that book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general explanation (which I can make more precise once you fix the formulas):  the identity will hold "everywhere" except on the branch cut for the hypergeometric function (i.e. on the real line, from 1 to $+\infty$).  On the branch cut, the choice of sign will flip the orientation of the cut, so that you get continuity in a clockwise/counter-clockwise manner.

Comment: @Jacues: Thanks I noticed the same thing about the parameter c and why it is not showing in the transformation. The equation can be found in Handbook of Special Functions by Yury A. Brychkov.

http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Special-Functions-Derivatives-Integrals/dp/158488956X

The transformation is given by equation (40) in chapter 8 as follows

${}_2F_1\Big(a,1-a;b;z\Big)=(1-z)^{b-1}{}_2F_1\Big(\frac{b-a}{2},\frac{b+a-1}{2};c;4z(1-z)\Big)$

Comment: My problem is that I am using this transformation to simplify an integrand that contains 2F1 within an integral equation that I encountered. Therefore,I was thinking which solution of the transformation of 2F1 I need to plug back in my original integral equation. 